# Communicate with web explorer

Tags: javascript, python, html, sqlite, flask

I want to do the following:

1. Load an HTML page with Flask (A).
2. When a register changes in a certain table of a SQLite database, notify the browser and load another webpage (B).

I am stuck on the second point. Could this be solved with Python and Flask (i.e., can you run Python code after the `render_template` sentence)?

I have seen that this could be done with Javascript using [this library](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/), but I am wonder if this could be solved with Python and Flask.

Comment: That would require some type of worker process to watch changes in db, then when a change does occur, would require some type of socket event to be emitted to update the ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, Flask-SocketIO's library makes it possible to create this communication channel.